# How long a time horizon should be for verifying the effectiveness of an investment strategy?

Tags: portfolio-management, portfolio-optimization, portfolio, asset-allocation

### Question

- To verify the effectiveness of a certain asset allocation strategy, how long a time horizon should be?
- Is there any academic paper regarding this topic?

### Question in more detial

- I know that appropriate time horizon varies depending on investment strategy. For example, high frequency trading (HFT) needs less than a second to prove its effectiveness.
- The appropriate time horizon that I am curios to know is for **'portfolio investment'**, which is asset allocation.
- If I want to argue that a certain portfolio optimization strategy is better than others, how long time horizon do I need?

Comment: Your reference to trading frequency is likely a big part of it, but I'd start first by defining 'effectiveness' in your case

Comment: @Chris 'effectiveness' of an investment strategy is, in my book, a perforance indicator showing how good a portfolio strategy is. For example, sharpe ratio and sortino ratio can be used to show the effectiveness of an investment strategy.

Comment: @Chris So we can put the question in other words as follows : To argue one certain portfolio performance measurement (ex. Sharpe ratio) of a certain asset allocation is valid, how long the investment horizon should be?

Comment: well, Sharpe ratio follows a Student's t distribution...seems like you could use this information to assess a given value's statistical significance at some level.